# Pandas calculation with boolean

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing data with pandas.

What I tried was like below to get value c4, but It gave me error message "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().:

```
def calcc4():
    lengthwl = pd.DataFrame(df_sample_merged.LWL)
    draughtforep = pd.DataFrame(df_sample_merged.draught)
    if draughtforep / lengthwl <= 0.04:
        c4 = draughtforep / lengthwl
    else:
        c4 = 0.04
    return c4
```

I think I got error because data type of "if draughtforep / lengthwl <= 0.04:" is  boolean but I cant really figure out what am I supposed to do to get c4 depending on (draughtforep / lengthwl) value.

Thank you!

////////////added//////

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10]], columns=['A', 'B'])

def calcc7():
    breadth = df.A
    lengthwl = df.B
    if (breadth / lengthwl) < 0.11:
        c7 = 0.229577 * (breadth / lengthwl) ** 0.33333
    elif (breadth / lengthwl) > 0.11 and (breadth / lengthwl) < 0.25:
            c7 = (breadth / lengthwl)
    else:
        c7 = 0.5 - 0.625 * (breadth / lengthwl)
    return c7
calcc7()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use nested [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function:

```
def calcc7(df):
    res = np.where(df.A / df.B < 0.11,
                   0.229577 * (df.A / df.B) ** 0.33333,
                   np.where((df.A / df.B > 0.11) & (df.A / df.B < 0.25),
                             df.A / df.B,
                             0.5 - 0.625 * (df.A / df.B)))
    return res
```

Comment: thank you for your comment! It worked but I have few more things to do which have more than two options and each have different equations.. Would you be able to advise me how I can handle it?

Comment: @KimHG, please provide a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50435841/edit)...

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've added sample correspond to way you advised I think. sorry for your inconvenience which ex-sample may have caused

Comment: appreciate for your advise!! It worked for me! thank you !

Comment: I did ! have a nice day